# PySpark how to sort by a value, if the values are equal sort by the key?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

For instance:

```
tmp = [('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('b', 1), ('f', 3), ('d', 4), ('c', 5)]
sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda x: x[1]).collect()

# in this way, it only sorts the value.
[('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('b', 1), ('f', 3), ('d', 4), ('c', 5)]
```

What I want is if the both of the values are equal, then compare the key ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ...)

The expected output is :

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 3), ('d', 4), ('c', 5)]
```

I know it's easy to achieve this by using `sortBy` twice, firstly sort the key, then sort the value. However, I think it may be not feasible if the dataset is distributed.

Is there any lambda function to settle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by the second element, then the first element:

```
sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]]).collect()
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 3), ('d', 4), ('c', 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this way, it can sort with the same ascending order for both element. For example, I want to sort the value in descending, but sort the key in ascending.

Comment: @DennisLi you can add a negative sign if you want to sort in descending order, e.g. `[-x[1], x[0]]`

Comment: @DennisLi or you can specify `ascending=False` (see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.sortBy)), but that will apply to the whole sorting function.